# Clear button on calculator App using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, calculator

I'm basically making a simple calculator app using Kotlin. I'm very new to programming so I'm not familiar with Java either.

Basically the app runs and I'm also attaching a screenshot of the App's layout along with the code on MainActivity. Everything works fine except the clear button. Ideally, I want the clear button to reset the value on the 1st widget(results widget) and let me start a new calculation. Like how a AC button works on a regular calculator. However, all it does is clear the value. It doesn't clear the calculation. When I select the next calculation it still adds/subtracts/multiplies/divides to the previous value that's already there in the results widget. It doesn't let me start a new calculation like how I would be able to do if I pressed AC on a regular calculator.

Hope what i'm saying makes sense. Please tell me how can I make this work. And again, I'm very new to programming so would really really appreciate it if someone can help me.

[image]

```
package academy.learnprogramming.calculator

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


private const val TAG = "MainActivity"

private const val STATE_PENDING_OPERATION = "PendingOperation" 
private const val STATE_OPERAND1 =  "Operand1" 
private const val STATE_OPERAND1_STORED = "Operand1_Stored" 

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



    private var operand1: Double? = null 
    private var operand2: Double = 0.0
    private var pendingOperation = "="

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val listener = View.OnClickListener { v ->
            val b = v as Button
            newNumber.append(b.text)
        }

        button0.setOnClickListener(listener)
        button1.setOnClickListener(listener)
        button2.setOnClickListener(listener)
        button3.setOnClickListener(listener)
        button4.setOnClickListener(listener)
        button5.setOnClickListener(listener)
        button6.setOnClickListener(listener)
        button7.setOnClickListener(listener)
        button8.setOnClickListener(listener)
        button9.setOnClickListener(listener)
        buttonDot.setOnClickListener(listener)


        val opListener = View.OnClickListener { v ->
            val op = (v as Button).text.toString()
            try {
                val value = newNumber.text.toString().toDouble() 
                performOperation(value, op)
            } catch (e: NumberFormatException) { 
                newNumber.setText("")
            }


            pendingOperation = op
            operation.text = pendingOperation
        }

        buttonEquals.setOnClickListener(opListener)
        buttonDivide.setOnClickListener(opListener)
        buttonMultiply.setOnClickListener(opListener)
        buttonMinus.setOnClickListener(opListener)
        buttonPlus.setOnClickListener(opListener)

        buttonNegative.setOnClickListener { view ->
            val value = newNumber.text.toString()
            if (value.isEmpty()) {
                newNumber.setText("-") 
            } else { 
                try {
                    var doubleValue = value.toDouble()
                    doubleValue *= -1 
                    newNumber.setText(doubleValue.toString())
                } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {

                    newNumber.setText("")
                }
            }
        }
        val value = newNumber.text.toString()

        buttonClear.setOnClickListener { view ->
            val value = 0
            if (value == 0){
                result.setText("")
            }
        }


            }


            private fun performOperation(value: Double, operation: String) {

                if (operand1 == null) { 
                    operand1 = value
                } else {
                    operand2 = value

                    if (pendingOperation == "=") {
                        pendingOperation = operation 
                    }

                    when (pendingOperation) {
                        "=" -> operand1 =
                            operand2 
                        "/" -> if (operand2 == 0.0) { 
                            operand1 = Double.NaN 
                        } else {
                            operand1 =
                                operand1!! / operand2 
                        }
                        "*" -> operand1 = operand1!! * operand2 
                        "-" -> operand1 = operand1!! - operand2 
                        "+" -> operand1 = operand1!! + operand2 
                    }


                }

                result.setText(operand1.toString()) 
                newNumber.setText("") 
            }


            override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) { 
                Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState: Called")
                super.onSaveInstanceState(outState) 
                if (operand1 != null) { 
                    outState.putDouble(
                        STATE_OPERAND1,
                        operand1!!
                    ) 
                    outState.putBoolean(
                        STATE_OPERAND1_STORED,
                        true
                    ) 

                }
                outState.putString(STATE_PENDING_OPERATION, pendingOperation)
            }

            override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) { 
                if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(
                        STATE_OPERAND1_STORED,
                        false
                    )
                ) { 
                    operand1 = savedInstanceState.getDouble(STATE_OPERAND1)
                } else {
                    operand1 = null
                }


                pendingOperation = savedInstanceState.getString(STATE_PENDING_OPERATION, "=")
                operation.text = pendingOperation
            }



        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try resetting the values of operand1 and operand2

```
 buttonClear.setOnClickListener { view ->
            val value = 0
            operand1 = null 
            operand2 = 0.0
            if (value == 0){
                result.setText("")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, the code works. Thanks a ton however, I don't understand the logic behind it. Can you please help me understand that as well. Would really appreciate it.

Comment: Does it basically set it to how it is when the app if first opened or reopened? Except this time we are setting the value to 0. This is how I understood it. Kindly correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @AaqibQuraishy Yes, It just resets the variables to the initial values (the values when the app if first opened or reopened)